# Restore normal workflow after activity opening

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-activity

Let's take a simple example, I have an application that present a HomeActivity, this activity can lead to a RssListActivity (that list RSS items) which can lead to a third ItemDetailActivity which simply provide a detailed view of my RSS item. Some notifications may lead to the opening of ItemDetailActivity on a defined article.

My point is, in the case of a notification, to restore the normal workflow i.e. when the user click on the back button he is bring to the RssListActivity and another click on the back button brings to the HomeActivity.

Of course I would really like not to have to override a custom onKeyDown() on each of these activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly,

You want to make sure that in the flow:

`Home > Task1 > Task2`

That if a notification is called to start "Task1" then the backstack will look like this:

`Home > Task2 > Task1`

You can do this by adding [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to the Intent which is calling Task1. It should reorder the Activity (if running) to the top of the Backstack.

Comment: Thanks ! The correct flag to achieve my goal is Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must not reorder the activities, It's better to give to the user the two ways of navigation. Android way that the user is used to, and if your applications have some kind of hierarchy that needs to preserve you can have a ActionBar in your application with a button to go back (in the hierarchical way)

Also, I think the only way to do what you want is overriding the onKeyDown method.